# Constructor error in my sub class constructor

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

Here is the Assignment:

Design and implement a class representing a Person along with 3 subclasses using the following guidelines:

a.Create a class named Person and its three subclasses named Employee, Student, Retired.

b.The Person has the following data fields: name, year_of_birth, isStudying, and isEmployed. It also has methods for setting and getting the values of each of the fields along with a method to calculate the current age and display the status of a Person. A constructor that sets the isStudying and isEmployed fields to false is also included in the Person class. You are welcome to add additional data fields and methods if you like.

1.Finally, create a Java test class that simulates using your Person class. In your test class you should at a minimum: a) Construct 4 instances of a Person, b) print the names of your instances c) print the status of your instances based on the values of their age, isStudying and isEmployed attributes.

```
public class Person2 {//begin class
    //declare variables
    String name;
    int year_of_birth;
    boolean isStudying;
    boolean isEmployed;
    int age;

public Person2(String name, int year_of_birth, boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying, int age){//begin constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
    this.isEmployed = false;
    this.isStudying = false;
    this.age = age;
}//end constructor

public int getYear(){//get year method
        return year_of_birth;
}//end method

public String getName(){//get name method
        return name;
}//end method

public boolean getEmployed(){//get employed method
        return isEmployed;
}//end method

public boolean getStudying(){//get employed method
        return isStudying;
    }//end method

public int getAge(){//get year method
        age = 2014 - year_of_birth;
    return age;
}//end method

public void setName(String name){//set name method
        this.name = name;
}//end method

public void setYear (int year){//set year method
        this.year_of_birth = year;
}//end method

public void setEmployed(boolean employed){//set employed method
        this.isEmployed = employed;
}//end method

public void setAge (int age){//set year method
        this.age = age;
}//end method

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
}

}

class Student extends Person2 {//begin class

    public Student(String name, int year_of_birth, boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying, int age){//begin constructor
        this.name = name;
        this.year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
        this.isEmployed = isEmployed;
        this.isStudying = isStudying;
        this.age = age;
}//end constructor)

    @Override
    public int getYear(){//get year method
        return year_of_birth;
    }//end method

    @Override
    public String getName(){//get name method
        return name;
    }//end method

    @Override
    public boolean getEmployed(){//get employed method
        return isEmployed = false;
    }//end method

    @Override
    public boolean getStudying(){//get employed method
        return isStudying = true;
    }//end method

    @Override
    public int getAge(){//get year method
    age = 2014 - year_of_birth;
    if (age > 30){
        System.out.println("Person is not a student");
    }
    return age;
}//end method

}
```

This code obviously isn't complete I am getting hung up on this constructor error. It says "actual and formal arguments differ in length".

Comment: can you post where you are getting the error? Also you don't seem to be calling the super class constructor in Student?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that you are not invoking the super constructor `Person2`.  Your constructor in `Student` is trying to invoke a the default constructor (with no arguments) of `Person2`, which doesn't exist.

You only have one constructor in `Person2`, and should call that constructor from the constructor of `Student`:

```
public Student(String name, int year_of_birth, boolean isEmployed, boolean isStudying, int age) {
    super(name, year_of_birth, isEmployed, isStudying, age);
}
```

This also means you don't need to repeat all of that initialisation code twice.

You also shouldn't be repeating all the methods in `Student` that are in `Person2`.  If you take them out, `Student` will inherit them anyway.  That's the whole point in extending the class in the first place.  You should only override a method like that if you don't want the inherited behaviour, but want some `Student` specific behaviour instead.

Comment: and by default Java attempts to call (non-existing) no parameters constructor

Comment: See my edit about your code in general. Can you accept the answer if it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

When extending any functionality you should try to use that functionality...
Your `class Student extends Person2` but does it use anything from `Person2`?

Why do you override **all** methods and provide identical functionality in your subclass???

Comment: We are working on overriding this week in class. From the video in the class it says you need to do this when using modules in the sub class.

Comment: Watch the video again - any non-private functionality from super class is available in sub class. You only have to override it if you are **changing** the behaviour.